# Running a "parallel" git repo and keeping in sync

Tags: git, version-control

I am running a project that uses git for SCM. There are a few branches -- dev, QA, prod -- as usual.

I want to run a parallel repo that has the same code *plus* some set of modifications. Specifically, this would be an experimental version of the same codebase. But I don't want to *fork* the code, and have two versions going off in separate directions -- the experimental version would still need basic updates to the ORM layer or whatever for example. But, we'd want to keep track of the changes in the experimental version -- while keeping them in sync.

One gotcha: I really need them to truly be two separate repos.

What is the best way to accomplish something like this?

TIA!

Comment: [Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository and create local tracking branches for each remote branch as necessary. Your changes will be committed to the tracking branches, which will diverge
over time from its remote. Periodically, you'll pull changes from the remote, and your changes will need to be rebased on top of, or merged with, the incoming changes.

Not all forks are wildly divergent versions of the original. *Any* copy of a repository is technically a fork; it's up to you how closely you keep the two in sync. In this case, it sounds like you will never push changes to the remote. Instead, you will only ever pull changes from the remote and ensure that your changes remain compatible (i.e., in theory you *could* push the changes).